# Tkinter GUI is not displaying windows screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am try to make simple code and GUI. I am also using `mainloop()` for displaying. In pycharm works fine, displaying but when i want to double click on `main.py` file just appearing 0.5 sec. What am I doing wrong?

In pycharm works fine, here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

But `main.py` doesn't display.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
master = Tk()

#pack
#place
#grid
canvas = Canvas(master, height=450, width=750)
canvas.pack()
frame_ust=Frame(master, bg='#add8e6')
frame_ust.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.1)

frame_alt_sol=Frame(master, bg='#add8e6')
frame_alt_sol.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.21, relwidth=0.23, relheight=0.5)

frame_alt_sag=Frame(master, bg='#add8e6')
frame_alt_sag.place(relx=0.34, rely=0.21, relwidth=0.56, relheight=0.5)

hatirlatma_tipi_etiket = Label(frame_ust, bg='#add8e6',text="Hatırlatma tipi",font="verdana 12 bold")
hatirlatma_tipi_etiket.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)

hatirlatma_tipi_opsiyon= StringVar(frame_ust)
hatirlatma_tipi_opsiyon.set("\t")

hatirlatma_tipi_acilir_menu= OptionMenu(frame_ust,hatirlatma_tipi_opsiyon, "Doğum Günü", "Alışveriş", "Ödeme")
hatirlatma_tipi_acilir_menu.pack(padx=10,pady=10,side=LEFT)

hatirlatma_tarihi_etiket = Label(frame_ust, bg='#add8e6',text="Hatırlatma Tarihi",font="verdana 12 bold")
hatirlatma_tarihi_etiket.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)

hatirlatma_tarih_secici = DateEntry(frame_ust, widh=12, background='orange', foreground='black', borderwidht=1, locale="de_DE")
hatirlatma_tarih_secici._top_cal.overrideredirect(False)
hatirlatma_tarih_secici.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)

Label(frame_alt_sol, bg='#add8e6', text="Hatırlatma Yöntemi",font="verdana 10 bold").pack(padx=10, pady=10, anchor=NW)

var= IntVar()

R1=Radiobutton(frame_alt_sol, text="Sisteme Kaydet", variable=var, value=1, bg='#add8e6', font="verdana 10" )
R1.pack(anchor=NW, pady=5, padx=15)

R2=Radiobutton(frame_alt_sol, text="E-posta gönder", variable=var, value=2, bg='#add8e6', font="verdana 10" )
R2.pack(anchor=NW, pady=5, padx=15)

var1=IntVar()
C1=Checkbutton(frame_alt_sol, text="Bir Hafta Önce", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,bg='#add8e6', font="verdana 10" )
C1.pack(anchor=NW, pady=2, padx=25)

var2=IntVar()
C2=Checkbutton(frame_alt_sol, text="Bir Gün Önce", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,bg='#add8e6', font="verdana 10" )
C2.pack(anchor=NW, pady=2, padx=25)

var3=IntVar()
C3=Checkbutton(frame_alt_sol, text="Aynı Gün", variable=var3, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,bg='#add8e6', font="verdana 10" )
C3.pack(anchor=NW, pady=2, padx=25)

from tkinter import messagebox
def gonder():
    son_mesaj= ""
    try:
        if var.get():
            if var.get() == 1:
                son_mesaj += "Veriniz basarıyla sisteme kaydedilmiştir."

                tip =hatirlatma_tipi_opsiyon.get() if hatirlatma_tipi_opsiyon.get()=='' else "Genel"
                tarih = hatirlatma_tarih_secici.get()
                mesaj = metin_alanı.get("1.0", "end")

                with open("hatırlatmalar.txt","w") as dosya:
                    dosya.write('{} kategorisinde,{} tarihine ve "{}" notuyla hatırlatma'.format(
                        tip,
                        tarih,
                        mesaj
                    ))
                    dosya.close()

            elif var.get() ==2:
                son_mesaj += "E-posta yoluyla hatırlatma size ulaşacaktır."

            messagebox.showinfo("Basarili Islem", son_mesaj)
        else:
            son_mesaj += "Gerekli alanların doldurulgundan emin olun !"
            messagebox.showwarning("Yetersiz Bilgi", son_mesaj)
    except:
        son_mesaj += "İşlem başarısız oldu"
        messagebox.showerror("Başarısız işlem", son_mesaj)
    finally:
        master.destroy()

Label(frame_alt_sag, bg='#add8e6', text="Hatırlatma Mesajı",font="verdana 15 bold").pack(padx=10, pady=10, anchor=NW)

metin_alanı=Text(frame_alt_sag, height=9, width=50)
metin_alanı.tag_configure('style',foreground="#bfbfbf",font=('Verdena',7,'bold'))
metin_alanı.pack()
karilama_metni="Mesajını buraya gir"
metin_alanı.insert(END, karilama_metni,'style')

gonder_butonu=Button(frame_alt_sag, text="Gönder", command=gonder)

gonder_butonu.pack(anchor=S)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i want to double click on main.py file"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do `pip install tkcalendar` and `pip install tkintertable` in command prompt .

Pycharm usually gives a virtual interpreter that is in the project and if you didnt change it or let it be that interpreter, your python version that is in the system path might not have the same libraries.

I tried your code myself in cmd and it gave me

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "CSVParser.py", line 3, in <module> from tkcalendar import DateEntry ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'`

Trying to double click .py file gave me the same result as yours.